# solving a series of nonlinear equations for the zeros of Bessel polynomials

Tags: polynomials, roots

I am trying to find the zeros of the Bessel polynomials numerically.

I found an article by Shafique Ahmed [on the zeros of Bessel polynomials](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021904585900528) --- where [Bessel polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_polynomials) are related but not the same as Bessel functions;

$$y_n(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{(n+k)!}{(n-k)!k!}\left(x \over 2\right)^k$$

and (with coefficients in the opposite order)

$$\theta_n(x) = x^ny_n(1/x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{(n+k)!}{(n-k)!k!}\frac{x^{n-k}}{2^k}$$

The article by Ahmed explores recurrence relations involving sums of reciprocal differences of the zeros $y_j$ of $y_n(y_j) = 0$, and $z_j$ of $\theta_n(z_j)=0$, including:

$$\frac{1}{y_j}+\frac{1}{y_j^2} = \sum\limits_{k\neq j} \frac{1}{y_k - y_j}$$

$$-1-\frac{n}{z_j} = \sum\limits_{k\neq j} \frac{1}{z_k - z_j}$$

I found another article by [Campos and Calderón](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/2012/873078/) on modified Bessel polynomials of similar form:

$$y_n(z;a) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{n!(n+a-1)_k}{(n-k)!k!}\left(z \over 2\right)^k$$

with $(x)_n$ being the [Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol) but Campos and Calderón don't say whether it's the rising or falling version. In any case, they give a similar recurrence relation for the zeros of these polynomials:

$$\sum\limits_{k\neq j}\frac{1}{z_j - z_k} + \frac{az_j + 2}{2z_j^2} = 0$$

and they go on to say:

> This set of nonlinear equations can be solved by standard methods. We have used a Newton method to solve them up to $n=500$ and $a=100$.

**What does this mean?** How can I reproduce this on my own? I know about Newton's method but don't see how it applies here. I'm intrigued because using the standard `numpy.roots()` function it starts to fail for the zeros of $\theta_n(x)$ at around n=18, putting some of them in the right half-plane even though they should all be in the left half-plane, because of the ill-conditioned problem of finding roots of large degree polynomials with large coefficients.

Comment: more info on Bessel polynomials at http://dlmf.nist.gov/18.34

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, well, I muddled my way to a solution using the multidimensional Newton's method for $\theta_n(z)=0$, but I'm not sure why it seems to converge so well (tried it for $n=1000$ and it converged in less than 10 iterations, just took a while to do the 1000x1000 matrix math).

If $\mathbf z$ is a vector of $n$ complex numbers close to the roots, then we can compute $\mathbf F(\mathbf z)$, where the $j$th component of $\mathbf F$ is

$$F_j(\mathbf z) = 
1+\frac{n}{z_j} + \sum\limits_{k\neq j} \frac{1}{z_k - z_j}$$

Then we are looking for one of the $n!$ solutions to $\mathbf F(\mathbf z) = \mathbf 0$.

I found an empirical approximation of $z_k \approx \frac{2n}{3}(u_k^2-1) + jnu_k$, where $u_k = \frac{2k - n + 1}{n+1}$ for $k \in [0,1,\ldots n-1]$. (I'm an electrical engineer so I use $j=\sqrt{1}$ )

If I set $\mathbf z[0]$ to this, then one step of Newton's method is:

- compute $\mathbf y = \mathbf F(\mathbf z[m])$
- compute the [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) $\mathbf A = \frac{\partial \mathbf F}{\partial \mathbf z}$
- solve for $\Delta \mathbf z$ where $\mathbf A \Delta \mathbf z = \mathbf y$
- compute $\mathbf z[m+1] = \mathbf z[m] - \Delta \mathbf z$

In Python with numpy, I can implement this with

```
import numpy as np

def newtbessel(z):
    n = len(z)
    f = np.array([sum(1/(z[k]-z[j]) for k in xrange(n) if j != k) 
                  for j in xrange(n) ])
    return f + 1 + n/z

def dnewtbessel(z):
    n = len(z)
    A = np.diag(-n/z**2)
    for j in xrange(n):
        for k in xrange(n):
            if j == k:
                continue
            q = 1/(z[j]-z[k])**2
            A[j,j] += q
            A[j,k] -= q
    return A

def besselstep(z,g=None):
    fz = newtbessel(z)
    if g is not None:
        g(z,fz)
    dz = np.linalg.solve(dnewtbessel(z),fz)
    return z - dz

def besselsolve(n, iterations, g=None):
    u = (2.0*np.arange(n) - (n-1))/(n+1)
    z = 2.0/3*(u*u-1)*n + 1j*u*n
    for k in xrange(iterations):
        z = besselstep(z,g)
    return z
```

There's probably a faster way to implement this with vectorization rather than using explicit for-loops, but it works rather well; here's an example for $n=200$:

```
def debug(x,y):
    print np.linalg.norm(y)

z=besselsolve(200,10,debug)
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
plt.plot(real(z),imag(z),'.')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.grid('on')
```

which prints and plots:

```
3.45859771477
0.773818778431
0.0630477688053
0.00274964340127
1.03622480252e-05
1.37203728772e-10
9.13827025945e-14
9.09800074633e-14
9.08758580987e-14
9.05208423149e-14
```

[image]